# Turn off GMail mail delegation notice

Tags: gmail

I have granted some other account access to my GMail account. Every time I log in to GMail, this message appears

[image: Notice]

According to [Google help](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1355565)

> For about a week, this notice will appear for a few minutes each time you sign in to your account.

But I am seeing this message more than 2 months. How can I turn this message off?

Comment: Good luck, I've had this message for over 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this message anymore myself.

Have you tried to remove it with adblocking software, such as Adblock?
Eg, for Google Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom